# Css- top left folded effect

Tags: css

I have a container with folded effect on top left corner, but I am unable to hide top left background. Can someone please help?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Effect if in up no depend seemed. Ecstatic elegance gay but disposed. We me rent been part what. An concluded sportsman offending so provision mr education. Bed uncommonly his discovered for estimating far. Equally he minutes my hastily. Up hung mr we
  give rest half. Painful so he an comfort is manners. You vexed shy mirth now noise. Talked him people valley add use her depend letter. Allowance too applauded now way something recommend. Mrs age men and trees jokes fancy. Gay pretended engrossed eagerness
  continued ten. Admitting day him contained unfeeling attention mrs out.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I recommend you make some changes:

In the `.container` rules remove `overflow: hidden`, as it is apparently not visually influencing the result (assuming the `heigh` property remains `auto` -  since `<div>` default value is auto).

And you only need of `::before` (delete `::afeter`), but set `-2px` in the`top` and `left` properties and set `white` in `border-left` color instead of transparent.

it will look something like this:

```css
.container{
  position:relative;   
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  padding:16px;
}

.container:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;       
    border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
    border-left: 20px solid white; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container">
       Effect if in up no depend seemed. Ecstatic elegance gay but disposed. We me rent been part what. An concluded sportsman offending so provision mr education. Bed uncommonly his discovered for estimating far. Equally he minutes my hastily. Up hung mr we give rest half. Painful so he an comfort is manners. 

        You vexed shy mirth now noise. Talked him people valley add use her depend letter. Allowance too applauded now way something recommend. Mrs age men and trees jokes fancy. Gay pretended engrossed eagerness continued ten. Admitting day him contained unfeeling attention mrs out. 
     </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea considering only the container and some gradient as border and background:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-image:linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 16px, blue 16px) 2; 
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent calc(50% - 1px),blue calc(50% - 1px)) top left/20px 20px no-repeat;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Effect if in up no depend seemed. Ecstatic elegance gay but disposed. We me rent been part what. An concluded sportsman offending so provision mr education. Bed uncommonly his discovered for estimating far. Equally he minutes my hastily. Up hung mr we
  give rest half. Painful so he an comfort is manners. You vexed shy mirth now noise. Talked him people valley add use her depend letter. Allowance too applauded now way something recommend. Mrs age men and trees jokes fancy. Gay pretended engrossed eagerness
  continued ten. Admitting day him contained unfeeling attention mrs out.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this removes the background of the topleft corner

```
.container{

  position:relative;   
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #252525;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background:transparent;/* this is the new line, background transparent is the same as "removing" it */
        left: 0;       
        border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
        border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
}

.container:after{
    content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;   
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-top: 20px solid transparent;
        border-right: 20px solid blue;
}
```